# Problems with @PrepareForTest annotation

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

Is there any way to use one @PrepareForTest annotation for all the tests inside the class?
I see that despite writing for example @PrepareForTest(PortalUtil.class) befor setUp method, I have to write this again with every test method which uses PortalUtil.class.. Can be this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the annotation at the top of your test class.

```
@PrepareForTest(PortalUtil.class)
public class MyTest {
    ....
}
```

Note from the javadoc:

> This annotation can be placed at both test classes and individual test methods. If placed on a class all test methods in this test class will be handled by PowerMock (to allow for testability). To override this behavior for a single method just place a @PrepareForTest annotation on the specific test method. This is useful in situations where for example you'd like to modify class X in test method A but in test method B you want X to be left intact. In situations like this you place a @PrepareForTest on method B and exclude class X from the value() list.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.5/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html

Comment: the thing is - that doesn't work. Other methods needs it to write separately

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to write separately". Adding this annotation at the top of the class just eliminates the need to put the annotation on each test. Within each test, you can change how the `PortalUtil` is used.

Comment: @ŁukaszBocheński If it doesn't work, and the docs say it should work, then the best next step is to paste in a small example so we can figure out why. Otherwise, we have no idea what _will_ work for you, only what's _supposed_ to work according to docs and best practices.

Comment: From here, it looks like there are cases where you can have flaky tests when using the annotation at the class level: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977009/powermock-test-passes-then-fails